# mDns or similar Zero Configs to find Server IP

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mdns

My goal is to setup a server on a local computer in my network. and access that server through xamarin apps on android and UWP.
Id like to get the Ip address of my local computer using hard coded name (computer name or published service name!) since the IP should be Automatically assigned.

my googling directed me to use mDns which i could not find a good nuget to implement ( i need to publish the service on my local pc AND discover the services on my apps).
am I in the right direction or there is a simpler approach.
Thanks!
Edit:1. I'm only looking to use the apps in local network. Phones should be connected to wifi that provides auto dhcp
2.i need to access the server setup on local pc connected to the same network with auto dhcp /ip assigned
3. My app should be able to discover the ip of my computer so I can use the ip on my connection string.

Comment: _"published service name"_ - what do you mean by that, exactly?

Comment: _"since the IP should be Automatically assigned."_ - DHCP does not imply that automatic DNS registration is available. What is your network config?

Comment: mdns is new to me, as i understood i can publish my local pc ip adress as a device "or a service" such that it can be discovered by my apps, i plan to use web API app to work on my local PC so i can implement mdns "publish" on that !

Comment: You do know that it won't work outside your LAN's subnet, right? So if your phone is on LTE instead of Wi-Fi it won't work.

Comment: There are many existing questions about using mDNS in c#

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.